# How to keep navbar section link (state=active/highlighted) after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How to keep navbar section link (state=active) after clicking on it?**

Having problems keeping the link in active state/highlighted. Thank you!

[image]

Code (HTML, CSS, Javascript) can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SbnbS7SxSFJz_ceuhjhq5vLWtQtz4b45?usp=sharing

Comment: Which problems are you having, add snippet etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that, pls check comments in code :

```js
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const countSec = sections.length;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
function createListItem() {
  for (let x = 0; x < countSec; x++) {
    let ul = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
    let addListItem = document.createElement('li');
    addListItem.setAttribute('class', 'newlist');
    let secName = document.createTextNode(`Section ${x + 1}`);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    
    //  add css class to link
    a.classList.add("navlink")
    //  listen to click on link
    a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      activeNav(e) //  call function on click
    })

    a.href = `#section${x + 1}`;
    a.appendChild(secName);
    a.style.cssText = 'text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold';
    addListItem.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(addListItem);
    addListItem.style.cssText = 'margin-right: 15px; position: relative; right: 10px; padding: 15px 0 15px 0;'
  }
}
createListItem();

//  function for link click
const activeNav = (e) => {
  clearNav() //  call function to clear all active links
  e.target.classList.add("active")  //  add active class to clicked link
}
//  function to clear all active links
const clearNav = () => {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.navlink') //  get all links with previously added class
  links.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
}

function checkViewPort(element) {
  let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (rect.top);
}
window.onscroll = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach(function(active){
        if(
        active.getBoundingClientRect().top>= -400 &&
        active.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 150
        ) {
            active.classList.add("your-active-class");
        } else {
            active.classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
    });
};
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn_scroll");
window.onscroll = function () { scroll() };
function scroll() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 2000 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 2000) {
    btn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    btn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function goToTop() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
};
```

```css
body {
    background: rgb(136,203,171);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(136,203,171,1) 0%, rgba(0,13,60,1) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    color: #fff;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 2em 1rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    h1 {
        font-size: 7em;
        margin: 2em 4rem 1em;
    }
}
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc1;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: #eee;
}
main {
    margin: 10vh 1em 10vh;
}
.main-hero {
    min-height: 40vh;
    padding-top: 3em;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80vh;
}

/*  class for active link */
.active {
    background-color: #83c4f8 !important;
}

.navbar__menu ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.navbar__menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    transition: ease 0.3s all;
}
.page__header {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}
.page__footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}
.page__footer p{
    color: #fff;
}
.landing__container {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    .landing__container {
        max-width: 50em;
        padding: 4em;
    }
}
section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right; 
}
section:nth-of-type(odd) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.187);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 20vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}
section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}
section:nth-of-type(3n) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}
section:nth-of-type(3n + 1) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 20vw;
    bottom: -5em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 15vh;
    height: 15vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}
.newlist a{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: transparent;
    border-color: #1172c4;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px !important;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    line-height: 15px;
    }
    .newlist a{
    color:#1172c4 !important;
    }
    .newlist a:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background: #1172c4;
    border-color: #1172c4;
    }
    li.newlist:hover a{
    color:#ffffff !important;
    }
    .newlist:active {
    border-radius: 22px;
    }
    .btn_scroll {
    display: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
  }
section.your-active-class {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
section.your-active-class .landing__container::before {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}
section.your-active-class .landing__container::after {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-1em)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-1em) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE >
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <a onclick="goToTop()" class="btn_scroll btn_scroll--active" style="font-size: 60px; font-weight:bolder;">&uarr;</a>
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy All rights reserved</p>
  </footer>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```